Elasticsearch Date histogram aggregation: round up timestamp key?
I have an Elasticsearch query that aggregates data for every specified interval.
GET test-index/_search
{"size": 0, 
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "match":{ "devEui":"xxx"}
            },
            {
               "range":{
                  "timestamp":{
                     "gte":"2024-09-30T22:20:00.000Z",
                     "lte":"2024-10-01T02:20:00.000Z"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
      "thumbnails":{
         "date_histogram":{
            "field":"timestamp",
            "interval":"300s"
         },
         "aggs":{
            "attribute_data":{"avg":{"field":"signalStrength"}}
         }
      }
   }
}

This query aggregates data into 5 minute buckets and sets the key as the rounded down timestamp (e.g. data from 2024-09-30T22:20:00.000Z to 2024-09-30T22:25:00.000Z gets aggregated to bucket with key as 2024-09-30T22:20:00.000Z).
How can I round up the key so that data from 2024-09-30T22:20:00.000Z to 2024-09-30T22:25:00.000Z gets aggregated to bucket with key as 2024-09-30T22:25:00.000Z?
Currently, I am updating the timestamp after I query, but would like the query to handle this.
I am using Elasticsearch 7.10.
Thank you.
